# implement reverse of baker map(BAKER MAP DERANDOMIZATION)

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm using baker map randomization to randomize the pixels of image, using the code :

```
X=imread('cameraman.tif');
X=imresize(X,[472 472]);
% divisors = [ 2 4 2 ];
divisors = [8 8 8 59 59 4 4 118 118 4 2 4 4 59 8 4 1 ];

[x,y] = size(X);

offsets = sum(divisors)-fliplr(cumsum(fliplr(divisors)));

if any(mod(y,divisors)) && ~(sum(divisors) == y)
    disp('invalid divisor vector')
    return
end

blocks = @(div) cell2mat( ...          % converts final result into matrix
                cellfun(@mtimes, ...   % multiplies the next two inputs A,B
                repmat...             % A...
                ({ones(x/div,div)},...  % cell with a matrix of ones in size of one subblock, e.g. [1,1;1;1;1;1;1;1]
                div,1),...             % which is replicated div-times according to actual by cellfun processed divisor
                num2cell(1:div)',...   % creates a vector [1,2,3,4...] according to the number of divisors, so so finally every Block A gets an increasing factor 
               'UniformOutput',false));% necessary additional property of
cellfun


I = [];
for ii = 1:numel(divisors);
     I = [I, blocks(divisors(ii))+offsets(ii)];
end

%create Baker map
Y = flipud(X);
Z = [];
for jj=1:I(end)
    Z = [Z; Y(I==jj)'];
end


Z = flipud(Z);
figure,
imshow(Z);
end
```

[image: after applying this code to image cameramnn.tif]

i want to implement reverse process of this randomization process to get back pixels in initial order.

The link to the document which I am working on is: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.39.5132&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: So what is the problem? It's not clear what you're asking. Please specify the issues clearly.

Comment: i want to know the reverse process of baker map to get back the original cameramann image.

Comment: embedded linked image